# how to use multiple left_joins without leftover NAS

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, left-join

I am working with a handful of dataframes whose information I would like to combine.

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2), year = c(1990, 2000, 1990, 2000))
df1990 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2), year = c(1990, 1990), X= c(1, 2))
df2000 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2), year = c(2000, 2000), X= c(1, 2))
```

Above is code for creating toy inputs.
I want to append the information in df2 and df3 to df1, resulting in a dataframe like this

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2), year = c(1990, 2000, 1990, 2000), X = c(1, 1, 2, 2))
```

To do this, my first thought was to use `left_join()` but I can only do this successfully once -- it works with the first attempted merge, but the NAs remain NAs when I try to do a second merge.
So I run:

```
df <- left_join(df1, df1990)
df <- left_join(df, df2000)
```

But I still have NAs.
Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Do you need `bind_rows(df2, df3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by TarJae in comments, create the right-hand side of the join, then join only once.

Assuming your dfs are all named `dfYEAR`, you can pull them out of the workspace

```
year_dfs <- lapply(grep("df[0-9]{4}", ls(), value = TRUE), get)
```

(even better would be to load them into a list to begin with)

Then join the two tables

```
# base-r
merge(df1, do.call(rbind, year_dfs))

# dplyr
year_dfs |> bind_rows() |> right_join(df1)
```

Note that if you have non-unique combinations of id and year in the `year_dfs`, you will end up with more rows than `df1` started with.

Answer (score 2):

Use `rows_update`:

```r
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df3) %>% 
  rows_update(df2)
```

output

```r
Joining, by = "X"
Matching, by = "X"
  X X0 X2
1 1  1  1
2 2  2  2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This works for the toy example, but in my larger dataset I get the error ! `x` key values must be unique.  Do you know a way around this?

Comment: It depends on your data structure, maybe `bind_rows` is actually preferable here. Maybe edit your question with data where this solution does not work

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect the complexity of my data a bit better!

Comment: What about `bind_rows(df1990, df2000) %>% arrange(id)`?